# How do I open a new file on blender 4.0

Tags: workflow

I upgraded to the latest 4.0 version recently but now everytime I try File->New->General it just brings up the last blend file I worked on! I want a new blank file. If I had wanted the last one I worked on I would have done File->Open->Recent...

If I close blender and open it again, it just brings up the same file. This wasn't the default behaviour for previous versions, is there a setting to stop it doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you saved your precedent project as your startup file.

To fix this, go to the menu File ► Defaults ► Reset Factory Settings, this will set your current session.
To make this your default, use the menu File ► Defaults ► Save Startup File.

Comment: Yes, I had done something stupid! That fixed it. Thank you so much.